# How do I interpret this JVM fault?

Tags: java, debugging, java-native-interface, hs-err

I have a Java app that makes use of some native code, and it's faulting.  I want to find out *where* it's faulting, but I'm not sure how to read the hs_err_pid dump file:

```
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x256cbc]
V  [libjvm.so+0x25df69]
V  [libjvm.so+0x25dbac]
V  [libjvm.so+0x25e8c8]
V  [libjvm.so+0x25e49f]
V  [libjvm.so+0x16fa3e]
j  br.com.cip.spb.single.SPBRequestApplicationController.processJob(Lcom/planet/core360/docgen/ProcessingEnvironment;Lcom/planet/core360/dsmv2/processing/ApplicationDataJob;)V+158
j  com.planet.core360.cgen.CgenProcessor.processJob(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/planet/core360/docgen/ProcessingEnvironment;Lcom/planet/core360/dsmv2/processing/ApplicationDataJob;)V+108
j  com.planet.core360.cgen.CgenProcessor.processJob(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/planet/core360/docgen/ProcessingEnvironment;Lcom/planet/core360/dsmv2/processing/ScheduledJob;)V+7
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x17af0c]
V  [libjvm.so+0x28b9d8]
V  [libjvm.so+0x17ad3f]
V  [libjvm.so+0x1a58a3]
V  [libjvm.so+0x18bc24]
C  [cgen+0xa6d6]
C  [cgen+0xae1e]  cgen_process_job+0x336
C  [cgen+0x10442]
C  [cgen+0x7714]
C  [cgen+0x38216]
C  [cgen+0x3a29d]
C  [cgen+0x37e3c]
C  [cgen+0x7558]
C  [libc.so.6+0x166e5]  __libc_start_main+0xe5
```

Basically, what are the 'j' frames pointing to?  Is `V+158` referring to the
bytecode offset in the class?  How can I trace back from this to the source
lines in play?

Actually, I'd love a general guide to grokking these dumps.  That'd be fantastic, too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a general guide have a look at these two links [Fatal Error Log Troubleshooting](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/felog-138657.html) and [Crash Course on JVM Crash Analysis](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/kohsuke/2009/02/19/crash-course-jvm-crash-analysis)

Comment: I was just thinking, "Now where did I see something about this recently?" Turns out it was Kohsuke's blog.

Comment: Link for [Java 8 Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/toc.html). For JVM crash (core dump file), use [jdb](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr011.html)

Answer (score 1):

i was confused too, what could "V+158" mean??
however explanation is simple, "V" is method return type and is part of method description.
(the description is consist of package name, class name, method name, param types taken by the method and return type) "V" stands for "void".

+158 is so called "bytecode index" - you were right.

Comment: Of course V stands for void, good of you to remind us. I learnt this from JNI, can you link where you are getting your source?