# Where are the JVM core dump files located on Windows 7?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface

I have a C++ application that loads the JVM for use of JNI.  It has been working for years.  Recently, the JNI initialization function JNI_CreateJavaVM() started to fail, calling the JVM abort callback function and crashing the application.

It is possible that some information regarding the crash may be available in Java core dump files, if indeed these are being written.  Therefore, I would like to find these files and study them.

However, I have never worked with Java core dump files before.  I do not know where they are located or what they are named.

I am running on a Windows 7 64-bit system, connecting to JRE 1.6 32-bit.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me where the Java core dump files might be located.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think they are by default dumped to working dir, you can check it with:

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Different JVM's might have options to specify a core dump directory.

Edit: There is a similar question and good answer here: [Is it possible to debug core dumps when using Java JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763368/is-it-possible-to-debug-core-dumps-when-using-java-jni)

Comment: My application is a C++ application that uses JNI.

Comment: Similar question with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763368/is-it-possible-to-debug-core-dumps-when-using-java-jni

Comment: mdakin - Thanks.  However, I cannot locate any .log files in $JAVA_HOME/bin.